# How to overide onClick(View v) so that all the buttons in my application can excute common task

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

I have several buttons and several activity. I want all the buttons should execute one common task other then its specific task. I want solution like below which I used to execute backpress for all the activity of application just by writing function of backpress once .

```
  public class BackPressActivity extends Activity {//Now My all activity will be extend BackPressActivity 


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showDialogToSearch();

}}
```

My Activities

```
 public class ActivityA extends BackPressActivity {  
}
public class ActivityB extends BackPressActivity {
}
public class ActivityC extends BackPressActivity {
}
```

So all my activity will respond to back press without writing it everytime.

Comment: create a Custom ClickListener and implement it ..

Comment: @MichaelShrestha gud solution  but here also I have  to make some changes in all the buttons

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this but I think it should solve your problem

create a custom `OnClickListener`

```
public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

and then in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);             

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSomething);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
   //Now all classes should extend BaseActivity 

public void onClick(View v) {
    doSomething();

}}
```

and in your xml file

```
<Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Comment: gud solution  but here also I have  to make some changes in all the buttons..belive me I have lot of buttons

Comment: do you want to implement it like the back button press??